# Single model dynamic database settings in Django

Tags: python, django

For example assume that I have 100 clients who uses WordPress and I have to write a service in Django which should return list of *posts* from WordPress's MySQL DB. The problem is 100 clients are having different database connection settings.

**I know** that I can use `DatabaseRouter` to switch databases which are already loaded in settings. But **I don't know** how to make a **singe model class** to use different database settings.

- I have tried mutating settings.
- I also tried mutating model's `app_label`.

But I later understood that mutating anyting in Django is meaning less.

### My Requirements

I want to create a model and dynamically change database connection. List of connection can be in a `managed` database table. But I don't want to unnecessarily load all the connection settings or create multiple models.

Comment: Do you really need to use Django's ORM here ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers No, but that would be good.

Comment: Well at least you know you can just bypass the ORM for this part and use the good old dbapi - if nothing better works ;)

Comment: Would it not make more sense to use the [Wordpress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts) to retrieve that data rather than connecting to MySQL?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  I thought that would be little tedious if there is no other way then I have to do that.

Comment: @bkmagnetron With the Wordpress Rest API connection settings shouldn't be an issue because if you want to limit access to the API you can do so by using the `.htaccess` to block all requests except those from the IP address of your application. The only issue I can think of that might cause problems is if the sites you're hitting are on older versions of Wordpress, and at this point they'd have to be pretty old.

Comment: The Wp REST api solution is certainly the simplest to setup and have quite a couple points -  if the OP's problem REALLY is with Wordpress posts, that is <g>

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers That did occur to me, although even if it isn't it's probably safer to expose that information using some sort of API endpoint and limit access via IP than to expose MySQL to the outside world. If these are all custom sites and all different it's probably going to be a bit too onerous.

Comment: @MatthewDaly thanks for your comment but I mentioned "assume" because the software is like WordPress but it's not WordPress. And I can't mention the actual software name. And also I have done this kind of things in SQLAlchemy so I thought it's also possible in Django.

Comment: @bkmagnetron Well, the principle still applies even if it's not Wordpress. If there's scope for adding the functionality to expose a list of posts as JSON or XML, then that's going to be a much safer way of doing so than allowing external connections to the database, and we're talking a single API endpoint with one method, so it shouldn't take long. It might even be that if you're using something off the shelf then it already has a suitable API endpoint. Authentication shouldn't be an issue if you just limit access by IP.

Answer (score 2):

I made something like that, but to change mongodb connections.
I created a GenericView that select the connection and use it on the get_queryset.

I'm using django rest framework, so I made something like this:

```
class SwitchDBMixinView(object):
    model = None
    fields = None

    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super().initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            request.user.database_connection.register()
        return result

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_object(*args, **kwargs).switch_db(self.get_db_alias())

    def get_db_alias(self):
        if self.request is None or not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME
        return self.request.user.database_connection.name

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.using(self.get_db_alias()).all()

    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        instance.switch_db(self.get_db_alias()).delete()
```

The model:

```
from mongoengine.connection import register_connection, get_connection
AUTH_USER_MODEL = getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL')

class Connection(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        pass

    owner = models.OneToOneField(
        AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='database_connection',
    )

    uri = models.TextField(
        default=DefaultMongoURI()
    )

    def register(self):
        register_connection(
            self.name,
            host=self.uri,
            tz_aware=True,
        )
        get_connection(
            self.name,
            reconnect=True
        )

    def get_name(self):
        return 'client-%d' % self.owner.pk

    name = property(get_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.uri
```

Comment: Uhu ok.. I'm afraid this part is way too Mongo specific for the OP.

Comment: Sorry, I have put now

Comment: I think django have similar methods for the default databases

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at `django.db.connections` (in `django/db/__init__.py`) and `django.db.utils.ConnectionHandler` (which `django.db.connections` is an instance of).  This should let you dynamically add new db configs without hacking `settings.DATABASES` (actually `ConnectionHandler` builds it's `_databases` attribute from `settings.DATABASES`). I can't tell for sure since I never tried but it should mostly boils down to

```
from django import db

def add_db(alias, connection_infos):
    databases = db.connections.databases
    if alias in databases:
        either_raise_or_log_and_ignore(your choice)
    db.connections.databases[alias] = connection_infos
```

where `connection_infos` is a mapping similar to the ones expected in `settings.DATABASES`.

Then it's mostly a matter of using `Queryset.using(alias)` for your queries, ie:

```
alias = get_alias_for_user(request.user)
posts = Post.objects.using(alias).all()
```

cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database

The main problem with this IMHO (assuming you manage to make something that works out of the *untested* suggestion above) is that you will have to store databases users/password in clear somewhere which can be a major security issue. I don't know how much control you have on the databases admin part but it would be better if you could add a 'django' user with a same password (and appropriate permissions of course) on all those databases so you can keep the password in your settings file instead of having to keep it in your main db.